# Symfony2 app/console Segmentation fault with stock 2.0.16 install

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to get Symfony2 working on my shared webhost, but when I run app/console it segfaults. It's a default Symfony2 2.0.16 install.

```
[kadaan@webhost Symfony]$ php app/console
Segmentation fault
[kadaan@webhost Symfony]$ php -v
PHP 5.3.13 (cgi-fcgi) (built: May  8 2012 17:05:11)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

I'm the owner of all the files, and they're all globally readable. I don't have access to the apache logs, so I can't check for anything useful in them.

Here's my output of Symfony's check.php, in case that's useful:

```
** Mandatory requirements **

  OK        Checking that PHP version is at least 5.3.2 (5.3.13 installed)
  OK        Checking that the "date.timezone" setting is set
  OK        Checking that app/cache/ directory is writable
  OK        Checking that the app/logs/ directory is writable
  OK        Checking that the json_encode() is available
  OK        Checking that the SQLite3 or PDO_SQLite extension is available
  OK        Checking that the session_start() is available
  OK        Checking that the ctype_alpha() is available
  OK        Checking that the token_get_all() is available
  OK        Checking that the APC version is at least 3.0.17

** Optional checks **

  OK        Checking that the PHP-XML module is installed
  OK        Checking that the token_get_all() function is available
  OK        Checking that the mb_strlen() function is available
  OK        Checking that the iconv() function is available
  OK        Checking that the utf8_decode() is available
  OK        Checking that the posix_isatty() is available

[[WARNING]] Checking that the intl extension is available: FAILED
            *** Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators) ***

[[WARNING]] Checking that a PHP accelerator is installed: FAILED
            *** Install a PHP accelerator like APC (highly recommended) ***

[[WARNING]] Checking that php.ini has short_open_tag set to off: FAILED
            *** Set short_open_tag to off in php.ini ***

[[WARNING]] Checking that php.ini has magic_quotes_gpc set to off: FAILED
            *** Set magic_quotes_gpc to off in php.ini ***
  OK        Checking that php.ini has register_globals set to off
  OK        Checking that php.ini has session.auto_start set to off

** Optional checks (Doctrine) **

  OK        Checking that PDO is installed
  OK        Checking that PDO has some drivers installed: mysql, sqlite, sqlite2
```

Has anyone else solved this issue, or can give me pointers what to check for?

Comment: Can you try with a different build of php?

Comment: Unfortunately not, my webhost only has 5.3 available to me. I have a phpbb and drupal install that both work fine so I believe it's something about how symfony2 is playing with php that's not happy.

Comment: Can you debug where exactly it fails? After that create a short script that replicates the problem and file a report with your host, it seems like a problem with their php build.

Comment: Ok, I finally traced it down to line 362 in Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php:

`$valid = $dom->schemaValidateSource($source);`

I did a var_dump of $dom and $source: http://pastebin.com/M4iTpMei

Comment: That probably means the bug is around the xml support of the php build.